# how to inherited all method to new class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

hi am new in python specially at OOP i just have this problem in inheritance where when i inherited the Grade class to Student class only the first method got inherited what i want is when you run the Student class the 2nd method also ask and the 3rd will print it

```
class Grade:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = input("Enter your Name: ")
        self.studentID = input("Enter Student ID: ")
    def grade_input(self):
        self.prelim = int(input("Enter Prelim Grades : "))
        self.midterm = int(input("Enter Midterm Grades : "))
        self.finals = int(input("Enter Finals Grades : "))
    def compute(self):
        print("Your Final Grade is: ",((self.prelim * .3) + (self.midterm * .3) + (self.finals * .4)))

class Student(Grade):
    def student_info(self):
        final = self.prelim + self.midterm + self.finals
        total = final//3
        list = [ ]
        list.append(self.name)
        list.append(self.studentID)
        list.append(total)
        print(list)
        

    


A1 = Grade()
A1.grade_input()
A1.compute()
A2 = Student()
A2.student_info()
#CREATE ANOTHER CLASS WHICH ASKS FOR THE SAME DETAILS AS GRADE CLASS, 
#ONLY THAT THE NEW CLASS WILL SAVE THE NAME, ID AND FINAL GRADES OF STUDENT)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "only the first method got inherited"? Are you aware that ``A1`` and ``A2`` are entirely different objects, regardless whether ``A2``'s class derives from ``A1``'s class?

Comment: All methods are already inherited. It's unclear to me what you are asking.

Comment: don't forget to add an __init__ to Student and call the superclass constructor there

Comment: A student is not a kind of grade. Inheritance isn't appropriate here. A student *has* a grade.

Comment: You never called `A2.grade_input()`, so `A2` doesn't have any grades that you can calculate `total` from.

Comment: oh i get it thanks man barmar